# Lyx beamer titles on new frames

Tags: beamer, lyx

I am using Lyx and Beamer in order to write my thesis presentation.
When i insert a title/section in a new frame , it does not appear in preview.. why is that ?

How can i add titles in each frame of my presentation ?

Comment: Does the titles appear in the compiled file?

Comment: No in the compiled file doesnt appear.. that my issue :/

Comment: Could you add a minimal working example (MWE), showing the issue ? It's close to impossible to help you otherwise. MWEs are described here http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Answer (score 2):

Sections and the like does not appear in the default `beamer` theme, so the short answer is to use another theme. You can find a list of themes in the [`beamer` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/beamer), or [the `beamer` theme matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/). (In the matrix, color themes are listed on top, layout themes on the left.)

To use a theme, go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble, and add `\usetheme{<theme name>}`. For example, to use the `AnnArbor` theme (seen in below screenshot), add

```
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
```

This theme adds section names to the top bar of the frames. To change the color theme, add `\usecolortheme{<color theme name>}` to the preamble.

You can also add titles to single frames, by writing it immediately after the word `Frame` (on the same line) in LyX. This will also appear in the default theme.

[image]